# MiniCssExtractPlugin public path not working

Tags: javascript, webpack-4, mini-css-extract-plugin

I am using `MiniCssExtractPlugin` to lazyload CSS files in my React application.

I have given `publicPath` option for `MiniCssExtractPlugin` but it is not taking this option value, it is taking `output.publicPath` option.

```
config: {
  test: /\.(css)?$/,
  use: [{
    loader : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
    options : {
      publicPath : '../'
    }},
    'css-loader'
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 26):

Seems as though your [not the only one confused](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/44#issuecomment-379059788), *52 comments* on how to get this right. The issue of [publicPath in html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/234) was similar and helped. However, the biggest help was from `npm run eject`ing out of the [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) and inspecting the `webpack.config.js` files.

TL;DR: You need to specify the save path in the plugin constructor.

```
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
  // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
  filename: "assets/css/[name].css",
}),
```

You might need to re-think the module output logic. 
Avoid specifying a nested path in `module.output.path` e.g. `public/assets/js`, instead set the *root* directory: `public` and set the nesting for the `filename` key: `assets/js/[name].js`.

You can then specify a `publicPath` in the main `module.output` that you would use for [subdomains or CDN's](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#outputpublicpath) etc.

The final complete config worked for me:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const publicPath = '/';

module.exports = {
  entry: './_src/_js/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'assets/js/[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: publicPath,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          },
          'css-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'assets/images/[name].[ext]',
            },
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader','eslint-loader']
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
      // both options are optional
      filename: "assets/css/[name].css",
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,

    }),
  ]
};
```

Comment: how do I change resource url relative to `assets/css/` if directory structure changes.