# Custom Angular webpack config, not all options work correctly

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-builder

I'm attempting to use [@angular-builders/custom-builders](https://github.com/meltedspark/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack) to set up a web font build during the normal build process. The package I'm using is [webfonts-loader](https://github.com/jeerbl/webfonts-loader). I have it somewhat working, but any of the loader's options that are related to file paths are not working. I think this is due to the Angular config and not the loader package, but I'm not sure how to set it up properly.

Code is below, but there are two main problems. First is that the CSS file is being output as `main.css` no matter what I try, and the second is that the CSS file references the font location as `/fontname.hash.ext` (with the correct information filled in). The leading `/` is causing the files to not be found.

How do I adjust the config so that the additional path options work properly?

I added the relevant bit to `angular.json`, the custom Webpack config is being called:

```js
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.font\.js/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'webfonts-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin()
  ]
};
```

The `my-icon.font.js` file is below. Some of these options are being honored, but anything related to paths is ignored.

```js
module.exports = {
  'files': [
    './font-svg/*.svg' // works
  ],
  'fontName': 'my-icons', // works
  'classPrefix': 'my-icon-', // works
  'baseSelector': '.my-icons', // works
  'types': ['woff2', 'woff', 'eot'], // works
  'order': ['woff2', 'woff', 'eot'], // works
  'fileName': '[fontname].[hash].[ext]', // works
  'cssFontsUrl': 'testUrl', // ignored
  'dest': 'testDest', // ignored
  'cssDest': 'testCssDest' // ignored
};
```

I'm referencing that `.font.js` file inside `main.ts` like this:

```js
import './my-icons.font';
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `webfonts-loader`. Everything you need to know is in `mini-css-extract-plugin` docs. A hint, look for `publicPath` options. I'm on my phone, hard to type much.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51055490/minicssextractplugin-public-path-not-working This might help

Comment: @hackape Setting those options has no effect on anything, except for `filename`. Whatever I set for `filename` is appended to the word `main.`, so if I specify `filename: 'my-icons.css'` the actual filename will be `main.my-icons.css`.

Comment: Very hard to tell. Sympathize, man. I'm quite experienced in dealing with webpack problem, yet I feel reluctant to step in. I've been through so many webpack tortures. However, if this is very important to you, then setup a repo that can reproduce your problem and share the link. I can take a look. It could be things not covered in your question description.